# How common C++ implementations treats static_cast and reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, casting

Ok most answers on SO say that reinterpret_cast is most dangerous cast, can do whatever..what not.., it can reinterpret bits of one type like another type. So my question is why does `static_cast<char>(int(0))` works but `reinterpret_cast<char>(int(0))` not? **is it due to size difference of argument type and destination value type?**

`reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Some_double_var)` works.

How does implementation knows which cast works in what cases?

Thanks

Comment: The second example probably works because all pointer types have the same size. But an attempt to interpret `sizeof(int)` bytes as a `char` is not sensible.

Comment: @oarfish so it's size issue with `reinterpret_cast` i.e size of destination and source types must have same size?

Comment: I think that is a reasonable explanation, but honestly I have no idea.

Comment: The implementation knows what each cast does and whether it works because it is built to comply with a standard that has the definitions of what is valid, what not and what the expected behavior of each operation is.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Sir I get you sarcasm which probably meant -> have a look at C++ standard doc lazy guy :D . Thanks anyways for direction :)

Comment: @AngelusMortis: It was not a sarcastic comment. Compilers apply the definition of a language, how a compiler knows what is allowed or not is defined in the specification of the language. I did not intend to imply *look at the standard lazy guy*, just that the question *how does a compiler know how the language is* is a rather awkward question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `reinterpret_cast` is the most dangerous cast, but it can't do anything. It can just do the most dangerous things. There is a specific list of things a `reinterpret_cast` can do.  Converting from one scalar value to another is not in that list, since a `static_cast` is intended to be used for that instead.  The list for `reinterpret_cast` is basically:

- Doesn't cast away constness
- Converts pointer to integral.
- Converts integral to pointer.
- Converts between function pointer types.
- Converts between object pointer types.
- Converts between reference types.
- Converts between pointer-to-member types.

Each type of cast is intended to do a specific thing.  For example, a `reinterpret_cast` won't do the same things that a `const_cast` will do.

Comment: so is there a list for both casts?